# OPENCV how do i map two slightly similar images in different orientation onto eachother

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have 2 images from different sources, and want to map them onto eachother because they both contain different information.
[image: robot localization image]
[image: traversable_map]

i am quite new to opencv and similar toolings, is there a way to automatically find the right orientation and location of the frame of the other image?

Comment: If you can extract the walls (e.g. color thresholding) you need a scale and rotation invariant matching method. E.g. 1. find the right scale by matching the center of gravity and the average distance of all points to the cog of both sets. 2. Orientation could be matched with principal components analysis or a rotational invariant chamfer matching.

Comment: These two images are not "slightly" similar. They are quite different in scale and orientation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical image registration problem.

There are registration modules in [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.registration.html#skimage.registration.phase_cross_correlation) and [opencv](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/31/image-alignment-and-registration-with-opencv/), though I am not sure how useful is the one in scikit-image: their examples only include shifts, but you also need rotations. The module in opencv includes different kinds of deformations and also provides tutorials on registration and alignment.

Another option would be to use the [registration tool](https://antspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html) provided by the [ANTs software](http://picsl.upenn.edu/software/ants/)